# Mac OS X 10.9, Cannot find appropriate C compiler on this system when install cmake

Tags: linux, macos, gcc, cmake, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to install cmake in MAC OS X 10.9, and get error log below:

```
Error when bootstrapping CMake:
Cannot find appropriate C compiler on this system.
Please specify one using environment variable CC.
See cmake_bootstrap.log for compilers attempted.
```

but i've installed gcc in my os:

```
localhost:cmake-2.8.11.2 markyoung$ gcc --help
Usage: i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 [options] file...
Options:
  -pass-exit-codes         Exit with highest error code from a phase
  --help                   Display this information
  --target-help            Display target specific command line options
...
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: What happens if you follow the message's advice to `export CC=gcc` or `export CC=clang`?

Comment: Does `cmake_bootstrap.log` explain why?

Comment: actually nothing useful

Comment: homebrew makes mention of cmake build issues and 10.9. [this link](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/11030) provides some details.

Answer (score 0):

Use [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) if that's an option for you. After that:

```
brew install cmake
```

worked for me. Caveat: I had already installed gcc-4.8 via brew install gcc48 before that.